# How to design a container that holds different two types of object?

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

Hey … I am facing a pratical code challenge in my project.

Let's say I have a `Model` class has a property called `Configration`. The `Model` object has different type of configration. For example, The `Model` was made of by Two `Pipe` objects, then one `Lock` object and another ten `Pipe` objects and they have to be in sequence.

In my project, all entity classes are derived from an `Entity` class that only has `Name` and `ID` property.

Model.cs

```
class Model{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<ConfigrationEntry<Entity>>  Config {get;set;}


}

class Pipe{
    public int Length { get; set; }
}

class Lock{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

So I create a `ConfigrationEntry` class that contains generic parameter.

```cs
class ConfigrationEntry<T> where T : Entity{

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public T Entity {get; set;}

    public ConfigrationEntry(string name, int num){
        Entity = new T (name);
        Number = num;
    }

}
```

However, if I want to add this `ConfigrationEntry` into Model.Config List. I won't allow me to do that.

```cs
class Main{

  var configEntry1 = new ConfigrationEntry<Pipe>("Test1", 10);
  var configEntry2 = new ConfigrationEntry<Lock>("Test2", 3);
  var configEntry3 = new ConfigrationEntry<Pipe>("Test3", 3);

  var Model = new Model();

  // I cannot add this entry. IDE says it has to be ConfigrationEntry<Entity> type even Entity is the base class.
  // model.Config.Add(configEntry1);
}
```

So what's the best practical solution for this scenario? Right now I am thinking two use `Dictionary<string, int>` and use string to find the object.

Comment: ```ConfigrationEntry``` is not correct is it compliable on your side?

Comment: No. it is not. I cannot add `ConfigrationEntry<Pipe>` object to the `List<ConfigrationEntry<Entity>>` List even though `Entity` is parent class of `Pipe` but it makes sense. I think I need make `ConfigrationEntry` to implement an Interface. However, I would be more curios about what's practical solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right. You try to use covariant or contravariant (the `Entity` property is `get; set;`) and that's not working that way.

In your case you need to add an interface or base class that handles the `Entity` as base type and add those to the `List<>`.

Btw: There is a typo in `ConfigrationEntry`.

Change your configuration entry class to:

```
interface IConfigurationEntry
{
    int Number { get; set; } // is set required?

    Entity Entity { get; set; } // is set required?
}

class ConfigurationEntry<T> : IConfigurationEntry
    where T : Entity
{

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public T Entity {get; set;}

    Entity IConfigurationEntry.Entity
    {
        get => this.Entity;
        set => this.Entity = (T)value;
    }

    public ConfigurationEntry(string name, int num){
        Entity = new T (name);   // this looks strange!
        Number = num;
    }

}
```

After having an interface for all `ConfigurationEntry<T>` instances you're able to change your model:

```
class Model{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<IConfigurationEntry> Config {get;set;}
}
```

If you're using serialization for that `Model` you need to serialize any type descriptor to deserialize correct instances - but that's another topic and depends on which serialization is used.